# Sharing temp table to other connection in the same stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure which does the following:

1. Create a temporary table (`#tmp1`) from a `SELECT.. INTO.. FROM..` syntax.
2. Build a querystring and execute it using `EXEC(@STR1)`. The querystring also do a query to `#tmp1`.

The reason why the querystring is built on a string variable is because there are some condition in forming the query.

The problem now is because the 2nd query can't access `#tmp1` since it's on different connection. I can create a global temporary table and drop it upon completion but am concerned on the implication when multiple users are triggering the stored procedure at the same time.

Appreciate ideas or workaround for this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seemed that you are using temporary table to exchange data between queries. If so, maybe make use of Service Broker? Or use message queue based on normal table? What makes you use temptable?

Comment: I'm confused... you say that you have *a* stored procedure that does the following two steps, but you then say that the second step is being done on a different connection...